# Airflow: Copy local file to GCS

Tags: airflow

I'm using Airflow to copy files from local to GCS, implemented using the FileToGoogleCloudStorageOperator

My code:

```
dag = DAG('file-gcs-demo', catchup=False, default_args=default_args)

cloud_storage_bucket_name = 'composerdemo-bucket'

t1 = FileToGoogleCloudStorageOperator(
    task_id = 'copy-file-gcs',
    src = '/Users/jw/data.json',
    dst = '/data',
    bucket = cloud_storage_bucket_name,
    gcp_conn_id = 'google_cloud_default',
    dag = dag
)

t1
```

The DAG runs successfully and when I check in GCS I can see a /data folder created in my bucket, but the folder is empty with no file copied. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`dst` is an object, not a folder.](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/1.10.12/_modules/airflow/contrib/operators/file_to_gcs.html#FileToGoogleCloudStorageOperator) Change `dst=` to include an object name within the folder, for example `dst="data/data.json"`.